# How can I make bar & pie charts in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, bar-chart, pie-chart

I want to make charts, bar chart and pie chart. It has to take inputs from user and maps that input to the chart on run time.

Chart has to able to make changes as the user changing it on run time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

1. [Angular chart (using Chart.js)](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js)
2. [Angular charts using D3](http://chinmaymk.github.io/angular-charts/)
3. [Angular-nvD3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3)
4. You can use [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) also. You can use it with AngularJS

Comment: I have tried with Angular chart (using Chart.js), but my application is not showing the bar charts, it's hanging, I don't know why ?

Comment: Hi @Dhana. That is called a question, this is called a Comment. You should ask your question, as a question; so that users could have the opportunity to see it and answer it.   
If you provide your code and explain what you've done, users can help you, but without any hints, it's impossible.

Comment: any library that i can use with angular 1.3.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

I use data driven documents http://d3js.org/ there is also a good pluralsight course on getting started if you have a subscription.

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/d3js-data-visualization-fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [D3](http://d3js.org/) library to write your own SVG data charts and then wrap them in Angular directives

or

You can use the [Angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/) (it already has pie and bar charts) directives who already wrap D3 
all you need is to define chart options and input your data

if you rather work with Canvas than SVG, there is [vis.js](https://github.com/visjs)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of charting modules out there to choose from. http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=chart

Answer (score 0):

If you play around well with Javascript, you can also use the guide :
https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-pie-chart/